# Retrieve all documents matching search query and those of logged in user

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I'm new to ES and need help solving this use case.

My ES index has different types of documents (sample below). I need help with search query that returns matching documents based on this criteria: "return all documents of type 'lesson' & 'teacher' that has matching word in 'title' and only those'student' type documents that matches word in 'title' + 'teacher = <logged in teacher id>' "

For example: If the logged in teacher id is "imaa-tea-2" and search term is "science", I would like search query to return  documents 2, 4, 5 and 8 (8 because teacher = imaa-tea-2).

```
{
    "type": "lesson",
    "id": 1,
    "subject": "mathematics",
    "title": "second grade additions",
    "class": "second",
    "link": "http://myskoolblhahblha/simple_add",
    "id": "math2-11",
    "description": "this is custom syllabus for imaa"
}

{
    "type": "lesson",
    "id": 2,
    "subject": "science",
    "title": "living things",
    "class": "second",
    "link": "http://myskoolblhahblha/life",
    "id": "sc2-01",
    "description": "this is custom syllabus for imaa and mitkids"
}

{
    "type": "teacher",
    "id": 3,
    "title": "second grade math teacher at imaa",
    "details": {
        "id": "imaa-tea-1",
        "name": "david jack",
        "school": "institue of math & science for all ages",
        "degree": "bachelor of applied mathematics"
    }
}

{
    "type": "teacher",
    "id": 4,
    "title": "second grade science teacher at imaa",
    "details": {
        "id": "imaa-tea-2",
        "name": "john wick",
        "school": "institue of math & science for all ages",
        "degree": "bachelor of science"
    }
}

{
    "type": "teacher",
    "id": 5,
    "title": "first grade science teacher at salsa",
    "details": {
        "id": "salsa-1",
        "name": "big hero",
        "school": "salsa elementary school",
        "degree": "bachelor of education"
    }
}

{
    "type": "student",
    "id": 6,
    "title": "student of imaa",
    "id": "imaa-stu-1",
    "name": "lilly john",
    "class": "second",
    "school": "institue of math & science for all ages",
    "teacher": "imaa-tea-1"
}

{
    "type": "student",
    "id": 7,
    "title": "math student of imaa",
    "id": "imaa-stu-2",
    "name": "kala jam",
    "class": "second",
    "school": "institue of math & science for all ages",
    "teacher": "imaa-tea-2"

}

{
    "type": "student",
    "id": 8,
    "title": "science student of imaa",
    "id": "imaa-stu-3",
    "name": "adam dima",
    "class": "third",
    "school": "institue of math & science for all ages",
    "teacher": "imaa-tea-2"
}

{
    "type": "student",
    "id": 9,
    "title": "science student of salsa",
    "id": "salsa-stu-3",
    "name": "mary kumar",
    "class": "first",
    "school": "salsa elementary",
    "teacher": "salsa-1"
}
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work.   {
  "query": {
      "bool": {
            "match": {
                "title": {
                "query": "science"
                }
            },
            "must": {
                "teacher": {
                "query": "imaa-tea-2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }

Answer (score 1):

### Lets Revise the question

As I have understood, you are looking for such below conditions:

- all documents should have `science` in their title field.
- one of below conditions should be met:

  - type is `teacher` or `lesson`
  - type is `student` AND the teacher field is `<logged in teacher id>`

based on this explanation we expect the query to return 4, 5 and 8 docs.

> Notice that you have also mentioned the document **2**, though it has `science` as `subject` not `title`

### Query

you can make such complicated queries including And, Ors using [BooleanQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). here is an example for the documents you provided:

```js
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [ // this condition must be met for all documents!
        {"match": {
          "title": "science"
        }}
      ], 
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
// here we have multiple conditions which at least one of them should be met.
//(type is teacher or lesson) OR (the type is student AND the teacher is imaa-tea-2)
      "should": [ 
        {
          "term": {
            "type.keyword": {
              "value": "teacher"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "type.keyword": {
              "value": "lesson"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {"term": {
                "type.keyword": {
                  "value": "student"
                }
              }},
              {
                "term": {
                  "teacher.keyword": {
                    "value": "imaa-tea-2"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> Note: you might be wondered why I have used the `type.keyword` instead of `type` which its explanation is beyond the scope of this question. So I hope that you have simply gotten the main point of my answer, to solve your problem.